# TypeError: promovePeao() missing 1 required positional argument: 'player'

Tags: python, typeerror

I've got the following code:

```
if(promovePeao(board,player) or (not getMovesPecas(board)['W'])):
   print("HELLO")
```

My intention is to check if there are any players in the last row of the boards

```
def promovePeao(self, board, player):
    if(player == 'B'):
        for a in (1,9):
            if(board[(1,a)] == player):
                return True
        return False
    else:
        for b in (1,9):
            if(board[(8,b)] == player):
                return True
        return False
```

But when I execute the code, I receive the error:

```
TypeError: promovePeao() missing 1 required positional argument: 'player'
```

Any ideias why?

Comment: Try removing `self` from your `def`...

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `promovePeao` like a method, but calling it like a function. You are getting the error because the function expects the `self` argument, but it is not getting automatically passed because it is not being called on an object. Change it to this:

```
def promovePeao(board, player): #Note that there is no self argument
    if(player == 'B'):
        for a in (1,9):
            if(board[(1,a)] == player):
                return True
        return False
    else:
        for b in (1,9):
            if(board[(8,b)] == player):
                return True
        return False
```